# Add overlay image on top of drawRect

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

I have a UIView subclass and I am drawing in the drawRect method.

How can I add an overlay image on top of the drawRect target layer?

I add the following in the `initWithFrame` method:

```
    //add the image overlay
    UIImageView *overlageImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downloaderFront.png"]];
    overlageImage.center = self.center;
    [self.layer addSublayer:overlageImage.layer];
    //replacing the above line with below line does not fix either
    [self addSubview:overlageImage];
```

This image is not visible on top of the drawRect drawing.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff with the layer is certainly wrong. Just do this:

```
UIImageView *overlageImage = 
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downloaderFront.png"]];
[self addSubview:overlageImage];
```

You can play with the frame of `overlageImage` to get the position where you want it.

As to your actual question: put a breakpoint. I suspect you'll find that your code is never even running (because your view's `initWithFrame` is never called). That's just a guess - you didn't say anything about how this UIView subclass instance gets into the interface - but it's a common enough mistake, and one should always suspect the obvious first!

Comment: I am doing this, it does not work. drawRect renders over the view.

Comment: OK, good info. But then you should have said that in your original question.

Comment: So why not draw the overlaid image as *part* of your drawRect?

Comment: By the way, I think the fact that you're having a difficulty here indicates that something else is problematic. A properly written `drawRect` will not draw on top of a subview! However, your original question gives no info for deducing what might be wrong. Again, suspect the obvious: maybe you are adding another copy of your view on top of the first view.